# Does cycling through multiple images using CSS background url property save bandwidth?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a gallery for a mobile site where I have different stylesheets for different sized devices. Within these stylesheets I have several classes which simply set a background url property to each image I want in the gallery.

Only one of these will be displayed at a time. And I will be cycling through the classes using Javascript to display them in a slideshow type presentation.

I am wondering is this method more bandwidth efficient than having all the images as individual img tags within the DOM? By setting these url properties do they get downloaded to the user's browser when they first load the site or are they only downloaded when the class gets set on a div in the DOM?

Simply I am trying to avoid having to download all the different images to the user's device at once. If you know any alternate methods which are better for this sort of thing I am also interested.

Comment: Look in your console in the Network tab to view all resources which are downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, When you set the image backround, the image will only be downloaded if it is used, By this I mean, used as a style on some dom element.
Alternatively, you could 'change' the background-image css property using javascript. This way, you don't even have the image url in your CSS.

If bandwidth is your biggest concern, I would urge you to have a look at the inspector in webkit browsers like Chrome or safari, or with firebug on Firefox to see the 'network' tab, there you have a clear overview of what is loaded, how ( what order ) and how to optimize things. You can also make some stupid mistakes clear like downloading multiple times the same library from different locations and so.

Answer (score 1):

If you just declare the class in  css it shouldn't download anything before it is set. however it is a round question and the answer could take a lot of different shapes.

So I would say that yes it is a good way to do it, and it should be more bandwidth efficient (if you don't know that all the images will be loaded eventually anyhow, since you will typically have asynchronous image-loading either way it shouldn't matter much. I guess that if you only load one image initially the other images (i.e. the mentioned img tags) will not interfere making the load a bit more smooth?).

I find it to be a cleaner solution at least if you aren't sure which images will be viewed (which is likely to believe) to use your css-approach. also it's easier to maintain and provide a better design.

That you will be using javascript indicate that you are also doing the client side. And that give you control to choose what to do which is great :)

One alternative could be to have a local cache of the images as well, but that really depends on the problem at hand, if you will have different images and no real possibility to know in advance which images you will need (and perhaps not even how many of them?) then I think that the cleanest way is the way you purpose.

i.e. set up (or dynamically create) css-classes for images and handle all the logic in javascript.